# In GAMS; Endogenous relational operations require model type "dnlp" Error

Tags: error-handling, gams-math

```
Parameter   st(t)    starting time of curfew on airport t
        /11    540
         22    540
         33    540
         44    540
         55    540/;

Table   arr(i,t)    arrival               
                   11      22      33      44      55
         101     0       1       0       0       0 
         102     0       0       1       0       0
         103     1       0       0       0       0
         104     0       0       0       1       0
         105     1       0       0       0       0
         106     0       0       0       0       1
         107     1       0       0       0       0;

Table   dep(i,t)    departure              
                   11      22      33      44      55
         101     1       0       0       0       0 
         102     0       1       0       0       0
         103     0       0       1       0       0
         104     1       0       0       0       0
         105     0       0       0       1       0
         106     1       0       0       0       0
         107     0       0       0       0       1;

Variables
        db(i)   new estimated time of departure of flight i
        r(i)    new estimated time of arrival of flight ??
        v(i)    equal to 1 if flight i violates the curfew requirement
        z       total cost;

Binary Variables v(i);
Positive Variables  db(i),r(i);
Equations
        costt        objective
        c1(i)        constraint
        c2(i)        constraint
        c3(i,k)      constraint
        c4(i,i2,k)   constaint
        c5(i,t,tt)   constraint
        c6(i,t,tt)   constraint
        c7(i)        constraint;

'''c5(i,t,tt)$((dep(i,t)=1 and arr(i,tt)=1))..v(i) =g= ifthen((db(i)>=(st(t)) or (r(i))>=(st(tt))),1,1-M);
c6(i,t,tt)$((dep(i,t)=1 and arr(i,tt)=1))..v(i) =l= ifthen((db(i)<(st(t)) or (r(i))<(st(tt))),1,1-M);'''
```

I don't understand why I got this error. But I know that these constraints are the cause of the error. I can not think of any other way of expressing this constraint in GAMS. Can you help me?

15. Constraint in the photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymphl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You use the $( )-Condition on the equation domain of c5 to reduce the number of single equations.

When GAMS prepares the model for the solver it evaluates the $( )-condition and eliminates all (i,t,tt) combinations which fail the $( ) - condition. The problem is: your $( )-condition includes variables, whose values (in GAMS: 'levels') are determined during the optimization run of the model by a solver.
This means: GAMS cannot use the variables when it prepares the model for the solver, because their values are determined during the model run. That are the "endogenous relational operations".